# How can I test my code's behavior when receiving a null-but-not-0, and 0-but-not-null pointer?

Tags: c, testing, null, compiler-optimization, zero

I want to adapt a piece of code to be able to run on systems where the null pointer is not 0 in its physical representation. So far in life I've totally ignored the distinction between nullness and 0 - and still today, I don't work on any system which has this distinction in practice - but still.

So, I went and read the C FAQ about nulls again, and particularly [5.19](http://c-faq.com/null/accessloc0.html), regarding how to get an "actual zero" pointer. Well, I want to do this in a unit test I'm writing, but - I am worried some of those "tricks" will actually be optimized away by a reasonable compiler.

For example, using `memset()` and `memcmp(): Both GCC and Clang [see right through that](https://godbolt.org/z/eab1efoa7), so that this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int foo(void* p)
{
    void* ref;
    memset(&ref, 0, sizeof(ref));
    return (memcmp(&p, &ref, sizeof(p)) == 0 ) ? 123: 456000;
}

int bar(void* p)
{
    memset(&p,  0, sizeof(p));
    return (p == 0) ? 123: 456000;
}
```

becomes, say:

```
foo:                                    # @foo
        test    rdi, rdi
        mov     ecx, 123
        mov     eax, 456000
        cmove   eax, ecx
        ret
bar:                                    # @bar
        mov     eax, 123
        ret
```

So, other than compiling without optimizations, how can I reliably "force a zeroing" of a pointer?

Note: Thanks goes to @Lundin for pointing out that if I use `memset()` I also probably want to use `memcmp()`).

Comment: [`memset_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset)? It's the only standard way, despite being optional. https://godbolt.org/z/evW7Tb3f8

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Interesting option. Probably worth an answer too. However... there's good correlation between having non-zero null and not supporting C11 :-(

Comment: The `bar` optimized asm code is logical, as `p` is a local argument of `bar` and you don't do anything with it out of setting it to zero and test it against zero. Maybe you can get more meaningful results if if you return `p` and assign `bar` return to a caller local/static variable ?

Comment: You could call an external wrapper function to prevent the `memset` call being optimized away.

Comment: It's getting optimized away because the compiler uses zero as null pointer representation... it's a valid and well-defined optimization.

Comment: @IanAbbott: So you're saying I should/can rely on no LTO?

Comment: Yes, no LTO. Or write a volatile version.

Comment: Although `(uintptr_t)p` converts null pointer `p` to 0 on most systems with all-zero representation of null pointers (although the result is actually implementation-defined), it would be interesting to see the value on systems with non-zero representation of null pointers.

Comment: It is also possible for systems to have many representations of null pointers, one of which might be all-zeros. So setting the bytes of a pointer object to all zeros and seeing that the pointer object's value is null afterwards does not imply that the system's *only* representation of a null pointer is all zeros.

Answer (score 2):

`memset` is the correct solution. And since you compile with compilers that uses zero as null pointer implementation, it might be quite hard to block optimizations from happening.

You have a bug though.

- A check of a pointer such as `if(p)` checks if that pointer is a null pointer.
- A comparison `p == 0`, `p == (void*)0` or `p == NULL` checks if that pointer is a null pointer.

So `p == 0` does *not* check if the internal representation is zero. You'd have to use something like:

```
void* ref;
memset(&ref, 0, sizeof ref);

if(memcmp(&p, &ref, sizeof p)==0)
```

Which again probably won't result in anything revolutionary on a system using zero for null pointer representation.

Comment: I'm amending the code in question to use memcmp(), since the optimization happens in that case as well, and the question wasn't about my example code but the general issue.

Comment: @einpoklum Yeah but memset is the correct way and the optimization is correct, since the compiler you used uses zeroes for null pointer representation. In order to get something else out of it, you have to use a cross compiler for a system which _doesn't_ use zeroes for null pointer. In that case the optimization would have been incorrect.

Comment: And on that exotic system, that uses lets say 0xFFFF for null pointer representation, then `p = 0;` will set `p` to the value 0xFFFF.

Comment: I assumed OP's `p == 0` check was deliberate. I.e. it is checking if the pointer is null after setting its byte representation to all zeros. It is interesting to speculate what `p == 0` would yield for an all zeros, non-null pointer value. I guess the result would have to be 0 for consistency unless the implementation has multiple representations of null, one of which is all zeros.